# Как сохранить значение переменной через $_SESSION

Tags: php, сессия

Добра всем! Помогите нубу сделать супер красивую авторизацию!

Суть: делаю форму авторизации по SMS без переходов, первый этап получить телефон клиента, обычная форма. Второй этап сверить временный код с введенным на этой же странице. Суть в том что столкнулся с проблемой сохранения переменной после перезагрузки: Вот мой коды:

Первоначальный обработчик (мой роутинг): всегда запускает session_start(); на любой открывающейся странице:

Далее на странице авторизациии идет такой код:

> ```
>  if (isset($_POST['user_tel'])) {
>         $_SESSION['user_tel'] = $_POST['user_tel'];
>         echo $_SESSION['user_tel'];
>     }
> ```

Однако после перезагрузки страницы $_SESSION['user_tel'] становится пустым. Прошу указать что я делаю не так. Спасибо!

Спасибо за помощь! Весь код:

Это роутинг, он ищет и запускает функцию Start у конкретных модулей:

```
public static function Start()
    {
        session_start();
        echo 'Старт сесии';
        self::access();
        self::get_db();
        self::$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $urlparam = explode('/', self::$url);
        $class = $urlparam[1];
        $rout = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/json/route.json'), true);
        $pos = [];
        $modname = [];
        foreach ($rout as $url => $value) {
            if ($url === "/" . $class) {
                $template = $value['template'];
                $temp = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/../views/{$template}.html");
                foreach ($value['pos'] as $key => $module) {
                    $mod = "\\module\\" . $module . "::Start";
                    $pos[] = "{{" . $key . "}}";
                    $modname[] = call_user_func($mod);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        echo str_replace($pos, $modname, $temp);
    }
```

А это непосредственно обработчик формы авторизации:

```
public static function Start(): string
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        //header('Location: /home'); // сделать кнопку выход
    }
    if ((isset($_POST['user_email']) and isset($_POST['user_password']))) {
        if (self::chek($_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_password'])) {
            header('Location: /home');
        } else {
            $temp = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/login.html", true);
            $temp.= 'Логин / Пароль не правильный';
            return $temp;
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['user_tel'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_tel'] = $_POST['user_tel'];
        echo $_SESSION['user_tel'];
    }
    
    $temp = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/login.html", true);
    return $temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по описанию и отрывку, это точно должно работать

Обычно такие ошибки возникают из-за:

- браузер блокирует или удаляет кукисы, проверьте настройки
- строка `session_start();` должна быть в каждом файле, где вы используете `$_SESSION`. Также следует её размещать в самом начале файла
- сессия где-то разрушается
- проверьте путь сохранения сессии

Ещё пришёл вариант в голову:

- проверьте, вдруг у при перезагрузке отправляется пустая форма, из-за чего переменная становится пустой (исправляется `!empty($_POST['user_tel'])`

Comment: Добрый, в общем то проверил все по пункта:

Comment: Добрый, в общем то проверил все по пункта:

 браузер - при авторизации в сессию записываются данные юзера - и при перезагрузке страниц работают нормально 

строка session_start(); должна быть в каждом файле - все верно, сессию у меня запускает роутинг, поэтому она всегда запускается первой (для верности рядом с session_start(); вывел ехо, выводит на странице при любой перезагрзке

сессия где-то разрушается - это точно, хотя в другом месте работает хорошо

Comment: выложите на всякий случай весь код. потому что тогда выходит 2 варианта - либо где-то что-то в коде не то, либо проблема где-то у вас

Comment: проверьте путь сохранения сессии - без понятия как это сделать -( 

проверьте, вдруг у при перезагрузке отправляется пустая форма - в код добавил несколько echo и print_r $_SESSION и $_POST после перезагрузки код не запускается и в сессию не чего не должно записыватся

Сейчас в вопрос добавлю свой роутинг со стартом сесиии, и полный код запуска страницы.

Comment: по поводу пути - `phpinfo();` и параметр `session.save_path`. (место куда сохраняется сессия).  зайдите в директорию и посмотрите, есть ли там файлы сесси (набор букв и цифр)

Comment: http://joxi.ru/brRaqYNi7GlqjA

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключалась лишь в том, что я выводил значение сессии внутри:

```
if (isset($_POST['user_tel'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_tel'] = $_POST['user_tel'];
    echo $_SESSION['user_tel'];
}
```

Правильно сделать вот так:

```
if (isset($_POST['user_tel'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_tel'] = $_POST['user_tel'];
}
echo $_SESSION['user_tel'];
```

Простите меня за беспокойство! благодарю [Vladislav Tikhomirov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/387248/vladislav-tikhomirov)

Comment: ух ты, и правда! Даже не заметил...